# Drawing a circle in a submit button

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/GWGFy/

Is it possible to draw a circle inside the button on hover? I know I can do it by having a few `div` elements and JS, but maybe there's another, easier way?

```
input[type=submit] {
    width: 101px; height: 16px;
    background-color: #f68830;
    webkit-border-radius: 9px; -moz-border-radius: 9px; border-radius: 9px;
    border: none; cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/GWGFy/2/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Niet The Dark Absol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol) answered in the comments: http://jsfiddle.net/GWGFy/2/

```
button[type=submit]:hover::after {
    display:inline-block;
    content:'';
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color: #145;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an Input object we can't use CSS :before and :after pseudo elements so the closest thing I could think of without physically adding a div was adding it on hover using jQuery and then removing it once they leave like this:

```
$('input[type=submit], div.circle').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).before('<div class="circle">&nbsp;</div>');
});
$('input[type=submit], div.circle').mouseleave(function() {
  $('div.circle').remove(); 
});
```

**CSS** to style the new div

```
div.circle {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 16px;
height: 15px;
left: 50px;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
width: 15px;
z-index: 99;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GWGFy/3/) with my example Hope that is what you need.